# Merge rows in single SQL table

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have one table with rows like

```
ID | Key   | Value1 | Value2 | Type  
55 | 012018| 0      | 0      |  1   
55 | 012018| 50     | 10     | 1
```

I need to update this table to remove these duplicates so that my **ID, KEY and Type** is **matching** and Value1 and Value2 are **added**.

Get a result as

```
ID | Key   | Value1 | Value2 | Type  
55 | 012018| 50     | 10     |  1
```

Comment: Just note- i have many ID, Key and Type in one single table. for e.g. 115,022018,20,20,1 and 115,022018,30,30,1. And Value1 and Value2 are always numeric.

Comment: is there only 2 entry or multiple. If multiple then what will be the logic?

Comment: there can be 2 or more. I tried using Admir's answer and it works correct no matter how many duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use temp table to store your calculated values, delete them from your table by joining on Id, Key, Type and reinserted them. This way you will get distinct values in table and remove duplicates. I've provided example how you can do that.

Note: I've placed sql code into transaction and commented commit part, so you can easily test it.

```
BEGIN TRAN PrototypeExample

-- create temp table where we will store calculated data
CREATE TABLE #tempValues(
    Id INT,
    [Key] INT,
    [Type] INT,
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
)

-- insert calculated values into temp table
INSERT INTO 
    #tempValues
    (
        Id, 
        [Key], 
        [Type], 
        Value1, 
        Value2
    )
SELECT 
    e.Id, 
    e.[Key], 
    e.[Type], 
    SUM(e.Value1) Value1, 
    SUM(e.Value2) Value2
FROM 
    example e
GROUP BY 
    e.Id,
    e.[Key],
    e.[Type]

-- show data
SELECT * FROM #tempValues

-- delete data from my table 
DELETE 
    e 
FROM 
    example e
INNER JOIN 
    #tempValues t 
    ON 
        e.Id = t.Id 
        AND 
        e.[Key] = t.[Key] 
        AND 
        e.[Type] = t.[Type];

-- insert data from temp table
INSERT INTO
    example
    (
        Id, 
        [Key], 
        [Type], 
        Value1, 
        Value2
    )
SELECT
    t.Id,
    t.[Key],
    t.[Type],
    t.Value1,
    t.Value2
FROM
    #tempValues t

-- new data populated
SELECT * FROM example

-- delete temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempValues') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempValues

-- for testing
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION PrototypeExample

-- if you find it useful, commit
-- COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to simply group them by ID, Key, Type

```
SELECT ID, Key, SUM(Value1) AS Value1, SUM(Value2) AS Value2, Type
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, Key, Type
```